# Как убрать ошибку?

Tags: python, словари

При выводе кода происходит ошибка

```
    if city_friends['city']['title'] == city:
KeyError: 'city'
```

Как мне добавить условие, чтобы если эта ошибка появляется, то просто ничего не делать и переходить к следующему элементу словаря

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ещё вариант:

```
if 'city' in city_friends and 'title' in city_friends['city'] and city_friends['city']['title'] == city:
```

Comment: можно чуть короче: `if city_friends.get('city') and city_friends['city'].get('title') == city:` ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [
 { 'city': { 'name': 'London', 'pop': 12 } },
 {}
]

for el in arr:
    try:
        print(el['city'])
    except:
        pass

# Либо

for el in arr:
    if 'city' in el:
        print(el['city'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
city = "Hello World"
city_friends = {'city': {'title': 'Hello World'}}

_city = city_friends.get('city')
if _city:
    _title = _city.get('title')
else: _title = None

if _title and _title == city:
    print("Yes")
```